# how to implement a datetime picker in ionic 2 to select time range

Tags: angular, ionic2, datetimepicker, clockpicker

I want a clock-picker like the below image, where I can select a time range. As I have to select start and end time of an appointment using this time-picker, can anyone please help

[image: Sample image]

Comment: Where is the image? Have you tried this? https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/

Comment: I don't want native time-picker or clock-picker, but I want a clock-picker with time range

Comment: Did you get the solution?